# Convert a .tif raster in .img format in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, convert

I have a raster file in .tif format and I want to convert it to .img with QGIS.

Does anyone know how I could do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go `Raster->Conversion->Translate`.

In the output format dropdown look for either 'Erdas Imagine' or 'Standard Raster' depending on the flavour of .img you want.

Comment: Format selection opens when you select the Output file, see screen captures http://wiki.tuflow.com/index.php?title=QGIS_Export_Raster_to_asc.

Comment: Yes... then click on the drop-down box (defaults to asc and choose one of the dozens of different formats available - it is not restricted to asc!