# Is there a UK elevation raster layer available for use in QGIS for the WalkingTime plugin?

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, qgis-plugins, isochrone

I am currently trying to convert the OS Terrain® 50 shapefile into a raster format using the Rasterize function, but the output is just a black square which doesn't seem to have any data attached to it and isn't compatible with the WalkingTime plugin.

The overall aim is to produce walking and cycling isochrones which relate to distance but only on the road network, otherwise a simple radius polygon would work.

I am fairly new to QGIS and completely new to Python.

Answer (score 2):

OS Terrain® 50 comes as a raster file as well.

So from the download page:

https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html

Choose ASCII Grid and GML, from Supply format.

Comment: Thanks, I did not realise this. Unfortunately, after trying it out, this raster layer didn't appear to work with the plugin either.

Comment: What formats does the plugin support?

Comment: It doesn't state anything specific - there is a drop-down menu which suggests suitable layers that I already have in my project. The ones that show are all TIF Files.

Comment: You should be able to convert the ASCII grid to TIF: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170380/convert-a-tif-raster-in-img-format-in-qgis

Comment: It seems your original question (how to get OS Terrain® 50 as a raster) has been answered. You should post a new question for your issue with running the WalkingTime plugin on the raster.